# Change background of ion-item-sliding

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there a way to change the default white background of ion-item-sliding (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item-sliding) in ionic 4?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

change the background of `ion-item` not the `ion-item-sliding`

**page.html**

```
<ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item-options side="start">
      <ion-item-option (click)="favorite(item)">Favorite</ion-item-option>
      <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="share(item)">Share</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Item Options</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item-options side="end">
      <ion-item-option (click)="unread(item)">Unread</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
```

**page.scss**

```
ion-item{
 --background: red;
}
```

Comment: oh yeah...it turns out to be a silly question....I changed the value for the color attribute of ion-item and it worked...thanks